# RoR: nested attributes undefined method `build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-attributes, fields-for

i'm trying to put in the "client" form an nested fields_for to add his address at same time. 
Followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsgTT9hizZo which shows what i need.

well this is my code:

cliente model =>

```
class Cliente < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_one :local
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :local


end
```

local model=>

```
class Local < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cliente


end
```

cliente controller =>

```
def new
 @cliente = Cliente.new
 @cliente.build_local
end
def cliente_params
  params.require(:cliente).permit(:name, :telefone, :celular, :email, :local_attributes => [:logra, :cep, :uf, :city, :km])
end
```

cliente view

```
  <%= f.fields_for :local do |ff| %>

  <td>   <%= ff.text_field :km %> </td>
```

And the error =
undefined method `build_local' for #
in the cliente_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try-

```
@cliente.build_local()
```

instead of -

```
@cliente.build_local
```

Comment: Dunno Why, but it seems that the model wasn't working fine, i reinstalled everything and now is working perfectly Since ur response is the way it is now, ill mark it up as correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the `local` object, You first need to create `cliente` object

```
def new
  @cliente = Cliente.new      
end

def show
  @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:id])
  @cliente.build_local
end
```

Comment: it didn't showed me any errors, but didn't INSERT TO in local table neither